# Vigenere Cipher - decryption (by hand)

Tags: math, encryption, cryptography, vigenere

This is a Vigenere cipher-text

```
EORLL TQFDI HOEZF CHBQN IFGGQ MBVXM SIMGK NCCSV
WSXYD VTLQS BVBMJ YRTXO JCNXH THWOD FTDCC RMHEH
SNXVY FLSXT ICNXM GUMET HMTUR PENSU TZHMV LODGN
MINKA DTLOG HEVNI DXQUG AZGRM YDEXR TUYRM LYXNZ
ZGJ
```

The index of coincidence gave a shift of six (6): I know this is right (I used an online Java applet to decrypt the whole thing using the key 'QUARTZ').

However, in this question we are only told the first and last two letters of the Key - 'Q' and 'TZ.'

So far I have split the ciphertext into slices using [this](http://pages.central.edu/emp/lintont/classes/spring01/cryptography/java/kasiski.html) awesome applet. So the first slice is 0, k, 2k, 3k, 4k; the second is 1, k + 1, 2k + 1, 3k + 1; et cetera.

```
KeyPos=0: EQEQQSCXQJJHDEYIUTSVMTVUMTYJ
KeyPos=1: OFZNMICYSYCWCHFCMUULILNGYUX
KeyPos=2: RDFIBMSDBRNOCSLNERTONOIADYN
KeyPos=3: LICFVGVVVTXDRNSXTPZDKGDZERZ
KeyPos=4: LHHGXKWTBXHFMXXMHEHGAHXGXMZ
KeyPos=5: TOBGMNSLMOTTHVTGMNMNDEQRRLG
```

My idea was to calculate the highest-frequency letter in each block, hoping that the most frequent letter would give me some clue as to how to find 'U,' 'A' and 'R.' However, the most frequent letters in these blocks are:

```
KeyPos=0: Q,4 T,3 E,3, J,3
KeyPos=1: C,4 U,3 Y,3
KeyPos=2: N,4 O,3 R,3 D,3 B,2
KeyPos=3: V,4 D,3 Z,3
KeyPos=4: H,6 X,6 M,3 G,3
KeyPos=5: M,4 T,4 N,3 G,3
```

Which yields QCNVHM, or QUNVHM (being generous), neither of which are that close to QUARTZ. There are [online applets](http://rumkin.com/tools/cipher/vigenere.php) that can crack this no problem, so it mustn't be too short a text to yield decent frequency counts from the blocks.

I guess I must be approaching this the wrong way. I just hoped one of you might be able to offer some clue as to where I am going wrong.

p.s. This is for a digital crypto class.

Comment: Arguably this isn't a programming question if you want to know how to do it 'by hand'

Comment: Yeah I thought as much. The basics are necessary for building crypto, so I thought it might be okay in that sense. I'll vote up your comment because I agree. :/

Comment: ...huh. I could've sworn there was a cryptography SE site, but I can't find it now.

Comment: Yeah I couldn't find one either. I did look before coming here.

Comment: There are many cryptographers hanging out at http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There is a proposal for a cryptography site that is close to being launched: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/15811/cryptography

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question...

I don't have a programmatic solution for cracking the original ciphertext, but I was able to solve it with a little mind power and some helpful JavaScript.

I started by using [this page](http://cs.colgate.edu/faculty/nevison/Core139Web/tools/vigenere-cracker.html) and the information you supplied. Provide the ciphertext, a key length of 6 and hit initialize. What's nice about the approach here is that unknowns in either the plaintext or key are left as hyphens.

Update the key, adding only what you know `Q---TZ` and click 'update plaintext'. At this point we know:

> o---sua---opo---oca---nha---enc---rom---dth---ama---int---ept---our---mun---tio---ewi---eus---the---ond---loc---onf---now---hed---off---ere---nsw---esd---tmi---ght

Here's where I applied a bit of brain power. You start recognizing bits of the plaintext. `the`, `now` and `off` make an appearance. At the end, there's `ght` - this made me think the prior letter is likely a vowel. For example `light` or `thought`. I replaced the corresponding hyphen with `u` and clicked update keyword to find what letter would have produced that combination. The matching letter turns out to be `F`. I think updated the plaintext to see the results. They didn't look promising. So I tried `i` instead which resulted in:

> o--usua--ropo--loca--onha--eenc--prom--edth--eama--eint--cept--gour--mmun--atio--wewi--beus--gthe--cond--yloc--ionf--mnow--thed--poff--mere--insw--nesd--atmi--ight

Now we're getting somewhere. At the start I see something that might be `usual`, and further in I see `int--cept` and near the end `w--nesd--` `at` `mi--ight`. Voila. Filling in the letters for `wednesday` and updating the keyword yielded `QUARTZ`.

... So, how to port this approach to code? Not sure about the best way to do that just yet. The idea of using the known characters in the key, partially decrypting the ciphertext and brute forcing the rest is appealing. But without a dictionary handy, I'm not sure what the best brute-forcing method would be...

To be continued (maybe)...

Comment: Thanks, that would be a good way to work it out (provided the plaintext is in English and not scrambled twice). The textbook way is with either a Kasiski attack or Frequency Analysis, but I wasn't sure how to compute the Index of Coincidence for the slices.

Answer (score 1):

An algorithm wouldn't just consider the most frequent letters but the frequency pattern of the whole alphabet. Technically you compute the [index of coincidence](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Index_of_coincidence) for each possible shift and consider the maximal ones.